# How can I display custom snippet codes in the front end of my WordPress site

Tags: plugins

I have a Wordpress website and I want it to display raw snippet codes on the front end but it keeps showing the output. This is what I need to show on the front end

[image]

I have used several plugins like
a module within Elementor Pro ... highlighter, etc,HTML Editor, Syntax Highlighter,
Insert HTML Snippet, PHP Code Widget, Raw HTML Snippets, SyntaxHighlighter Evolved,
SyntaxHighlighter Evolved: VHDL Brush

How do I get this done?

Comment: Please note that plugin recommendations are off-topic for our site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Gutenberg:

1. In your WordPress dashboard, click Posts or Pages.
2. Select Add New or hover over an existing post or page and select Edit.
3. Place your cursor where you want to display the code.
4. Click the Add Block icon (the plus sign) and search for "code". Select the code block when it appears.

If you are using the Classic Editor

Display code snippets by using the preformatted text option.

1. Open the post where you want to include the code using the classic editor.
2. Enter your code in a text box
3. Highlight the code snippet and choose the preformatted text option from the dropdown.

Edit: Gutenberg Example:

```
<ul id=”mylist”>
  <li id=”list-item3″>text 3</li>
  <li id=”list-item4″>text 4</li>
  <li id=”list-item2″>text 2</li>
  <li id=”list-item1″>text 1</li>
</ul>
```

Screenshots showing results [here](https://snipboard.io/7rHMoG.jpg):

Comment: Thank you.
I used the first method to place this code 
  https://prnt.sc/y0vVkOPj74Zp

but saw this:

https://prnt.sc/9R3cE6vWMKEA

It is jumbled. How can i get it vertically aligned..

CSS?

Comment: If you have formatted the code properly (i.e. added your returns, spacing, etc) it should display correctly using the <pre> widget - example here of one I just did: https://snipboard.io/OY9VGa.jpg

Comment: did all that...

pls reformat using the code below


 <ul id=”mylist”>
<li id=”list-item3″>text 3</li> 
<li id=”list-item4″>text 4</li>
<li id=”list-item2″>text 2</li>
<li id=”list-item1″>text 1</li>   
</ul>

Comment: Just added screens and code test to original answer

Comment: @whisper-design, thanks a million.

just found out that the cause of the disruption is from the theme so working now on the theme. Thanks a lot